# Not able to run .bat file with complete path with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know this question looks silly, but I am struggling to run .bat file. I have a .bat file located in below path.
C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles
Notice the spaces in Root folder.
And I am trying to run .bat file directly by prefixing the path as below:

```
C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```

I am getting below error:

> 'C:\Realtime' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

I dont want to do "CD FolderPath" and then run ExportData.bat. The actual requirement is I have to run windows command from HTML page. Javacsript constructs this string and opens commandpromt to run the batch file. So I want this to accomplish in a single command which includes complete path to .bat file.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Add quotes: `"C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat"`

Comment: Thanks. running only "path/.bat" with double quotes is working fine. But I have to pass commandline args to .bat file. When I include args within double quotes again same error comes. :(

Comment: Command line arguments has to stay _outside_ quotes (or they'll be interpreted as part of file path instead of arguments for it).

Answer (score 4):

### Edit - a solution:

> ```
> C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
> ```
>
> ... Javacsript constructs this string and opens commandpromt to run the
>   batch file...

In other words, it must invoke either `cmd /C` or `cmd /K` to open command prompt... In your case:

```
cmd /C "C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat" "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```

does not work and the help (`cmd /?`) explains, that in this case *the first and last quote are removed*. Hence, your string could be any of the following (not exhaustive list, there are others) using:

- **surrounding with additional quotes**

```
""C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat" "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST""
```

- **alternative quoting**

```
C:"\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat" "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```

- [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (**preferred**)

```
call "C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat" "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```

- **`@` symbol**

```
@"C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat" "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```

**Proof:**

```
==>type "simple cli Parser.bat"
@echo  %%* = %*

==>"simple cli Parser.bat" "aa" bb
 %* = "aa" bb

==>cmd /C "simple cli Parser.bat" "aa" bb
'simple' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

==>cmd /C ""simple cli Parser.bat" "aa" bb"
 %* = "aa" bb

==>cmd /C simple" cli Parser.bat" "aa" bb
 %* = "aa" bb

==>cmd /C call "simple cli Parser.bat" "aa" bb
 %* = "aa" bb

==>cmd /C @"simple cli Parser.bat" "aa" bb
 %* = "aa" bb

==>
```

### Original answer:

Try next batch to see how parameters work:

```
@echo OFF >NUL
echo(
echo before any shift [%~1] [%~2] [%~3] [%~4]
echo   all %%* = %*
echo(
set /A "ii=0"
:loopfor
  echo param %%%ii% = %0
  SHIFT
  set /A "ii+=1"
  if not [%0]==[] goto :loopfor
echo(
echo after all shifts [%~1] [%~2] [%~3] [%~4]
echo   all %%* = %*
```

Output:

```
==>"D:\bat\cli Parser.bat" "a string with spaces" stringwithout spaces

before any shift [a string with spaces] [stringwithout] [spaces] []
  all %* = "a string with spaces" stringwithout spaces

param %0 = "D:\bat\cli Parser.bat"
param %1 = "a string with spaces"
param %2 = stringwithout
param %3 = spaces

after all shifts [] [] [] []
  all %* = "a string with spaces" stringwithout spaces

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Why downvoted?  The question is tagged `windows`, `batch-file` and `cmd` only, not `Javacsript`. Hence, my answer comes up to current tags!

Comment: After 24hrs of quest to find solution, this has been my final resort. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.Is working. I should construct  command string something like:

```
cd C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFile & ExportData.bat "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add quotes around the path and file name of your batch file...keep the quotes around your parameters if you need them.

```
"C:\Realtime Data Export Tool\ExportTool\BatchFiles\ExportData.bat" "DNCORR" "SYSTEM" "SYSTEM123" "SYNC" "TEST"
```